# Window/Screen Collapsible bottom follow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get my screen to follow my collapsible when opening it. My content is hidden under the collapsible and i tried it with `window.scrollTo()` already, but my script is only getting the current location of my bottom footer which it has when i am pressing the button.

[image]

---

Edit: 
My Code Snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/jz961rL0/2/

Comment: Could you show us your code? Maybe a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Marco I added the code to my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make this work using an [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver/observe). I've assigned an id to your collapible container for simplicities sake, so I can query it easier, then assigned an oberserver to it, and everytime the dimension changes, it will `scrollIntoView()`:

```
// https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapsible.asp
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

let collapsibleContainer = document.getElementById("container");

let resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
  // make sure entries only ever contains one element.
  // scrolling to multiple elements simultanously might yield
  // interesting results.
  for(let entry of entries) {
    collapsibleContainer.scrollIntoView()
  }
});

resizeObserver.observe(collapsibleContainer);

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
        content.style.maxHeight = null;

    } else {
        content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

Html:

```
<button class="collapsible">      
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1 class="headline">collapsible</h1>
  </div>
</button>   
<div class="content-collapse" id="container">
    <!-- Rest omitted -->
</div>
```

ResizeObserver is not supported by Internet Explorer, but fingers crossed, that you are not required to support that plattform

Comment: Hey, thanks for that solution. But there is an issue when reloading the page. It already runs down the page to the container id, which i haven't even clicked yet. Also, the content of my page is way more than just test, and it seems like that it has a fixed amount of scroll space down. Is there a way to make it the same amount as the height of my whole collapsible?

Comment: You can delay attaching the observer until your content is loaded.

Comment: that is the issue here. I want the content to be loaded and i want my screen to follow the loading content, so the user sees the content getting loaded, until it hits the bottom footer, when it is fully loaded

Comment: Reloading the page is not the same as loading content or appearing to load content. Only attach the observer when all your scripts are ready and your dom is rendered. After that, it's your logic.
You could for instance, attach the observer, when you click and detach it, once everything is done and the container is fully expaneded or collapsed.

Comment: I just wrote your code inside my collapsible code, so when i hit the button, the code loads the hidden content and after 1 or 2 seconds it will load the "Observer" Code and goes to the position of the container. But i want my screen to follow the content that gets visible.